# listview click alert has to be appear

Tags: javascript, sapui5

when i click on listview each time  a alert has to be appear.but alert appears only first time when i click on list.

xmlView Part

```
<List id="contactedit" select="somefunction">
    <CustomListItem id="custom1" type="Inactive" >
        <content>
            <Label text="this is label" />
        </content>
    </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Controller Part

```js
somefunction: function(oEvent){
    alert("this is an alert");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have only one item in the list. Once an item is selected, the select event will not fire again if it is reselected.

Dennis

Comment: thanks Dennis...but how to reselect the list can you give an idea

Comment: You can attach press event as qmacro has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The CustomListItem also has an event "press" to which you can attach your somefunction() handler - see the [CustomListItem API docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.CustomListItem.html) for the events that are inherited from ListItemBase.

So if you change your XML part to this:

```
<List id="contactedit">
  <CustomListItem id="custom1" press="somefunction" type="Active" >
    <content>
      <Label text="This is label" />
    </content>
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

then you should get what you want to achieve. [Here's a JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/majol/3/edit?html,js,output).